# Libgdx create a TextButton with background with uiskin.json

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I want to define the background of TextButton with uiskin.json.

Here is what i tried but didn't work:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$TintedDrawable: {
        img: { file: bg.png }
    },
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: default-round-down, up: img, font: default-font, fontColor: white }
}
```

So I want to make bg.png as the default background. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

Skin cannot read file locations from the json. If you followed tutorials for Skin, you probably instantiated it with a TextureAtlas like this:

```
skin = new Skin(skinFilePath, textureAtlas);
```

When you load it like that, all the images in the json must be available by their names in the TextureAtlas.

Normally, you need all your images to be in a single TextureAtlas, for performance reasons. So the best solution would be to add this `bg.png` image into your TextureAtlas, and then you can refer to it by its TextureAtlas name.

If you must load it as a separate file, then you must manually load it before loading your skin.

```
Texture bgTexture = new Texture("bg.png");
skin = new Skin(); //empty constructor causes it not to load yet.
skin.add("bg", bgTexture);
skin.addRegions(textureAtlas); // you will be responsible for disposing the atlas separately from the skin now.
skin.load(skinFilePath);
```

Comment: there is no way to define different backgrounds for different types of button in json file? I saw the way BitmapFont is defined, i can read the font png file location. Dont they work the same way? So for the thing like this, do i need to pack all button backgrounds to one texture then get the region? what is the right way to do it?

Comment: First question: There is a way...it's in my answer above, but it requires extra code for each defined image file. Second question: Yes, the right way to do it is to pack all the backgrounds into a TextureAtlas using TexturePacker. The file that BitmapFont references in the json is a font file (usually `.fnt`), not an image file. The font file references an image. A BitmapFont can be loaded with its own image file, or with an image that's in a TextureAtlas, but when using it with a Skin, it has the same complex requirements as I outlined above if you want to do the former.

Comment: Your method is what i am currently using. I thought should have something similar to css, make use of json file. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I think the reason support for that hasn't been implemented is that the performance would be so terrible if you didn't use an atlas.

Comment: Oh ya, @Tenfour04, You are right, it will be terrible to make it like that, make the game slower. I am clear now. Thanks.